# C- File input/output buffers and setvbuf()

Tags: c, file, buffer, stdio

In C language, does fopen() really creates two buffers, one for input and the other for output?

This is what my C book says:

> Normally, the first step in using standard I/O is to use f open ( ) to
>   open a file. (Recall, however, that the stdin, stdout, and stderr
>   files are opened automatically.) The fopen( ) function not only opens
>   a file but sets up a buffer **(two buffers for read-write modes)**, and it
>   sets up a data structure containing data about the file and ..

If opening a file with fopen () creates two buffers, in a writing mode like "a+", ie both reading and writing

```
FILE * fp = fopen ("file.txt", "a +");
setvbuf (destination_file, NULL, _IOFBF, BUFFER_SIZE);
```

what buffer does the setvbuf () function refer to?

Comment: The book is talking nonsense when it says “two buffers”.  Only one buffer is used regardless.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An open file only has a single buffer, regardless of whether it was opened for reading, writing, or both.

Section 7.21.5.3 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), which details the `fopen` function, states:

> *7* When a file is opened with update mode (`+` as the second or third character in the above list of mode argument values), both input
>   and output may be performed on the associated stream. **However, output
>   shall not be directly followed by input without an intervening call to
>   the `fflush` function or to a file positioning function (`fseek`,
>   `fsetpo`s, or `rewind`), and input shall not be directly followed by
>   output without an intervening call to a file positioning function,
>   unless the input operation encounters end-of-file.** Opening (or
>   creating) a text file with update mode may instead open (or create) a
>   binary stream in some implementations.

The above paragraph states the output buffer must be flushed before performing input (either explicitly or implicitly via a positioning function), and the same when performing output after input.  This is a consequence of having only a single buffer.

This also makes sense from a logical point of view as it prevents reads and writes from having an inconsistent view of the file contents.

Answer (score 3):

> what buffer does the `setvbuf ()` function refer to?

"Both" of them.  There's no requirement that the call to `fopen()` will create "two buffers for read-write modes".  Most implementations use a single buffer as that's all that's needed.

[The C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) implicitly supports a single buffer. Per [**7.21.5.3 The `fopen` function**, paragraph 7](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.5.3p7):

> When  a  file  is  opened  with  update  mode  (`'+'` as  the  second 
>   or  third  character  in  the above  list  of mode argument  values), 
>   both  input  and  output  may  be  performed  on  the associated 
>   stream.   However,  output  shall  not  be  directly  followed  by 
>   input  without  an intervening  call  to  the `fflush` function  or 
>   to  a  file  positioning  function (`fseek`, `fsetpos`, or `rewind`), 
>   and  input  shall  not  be  directly  followed  by  output  without 
>   an intervening call to a file positioning function, unless the input
>   operation encounters end- of-file.  Opening (or creating) a text file
>   with update mode may instead open (or create) a binary stream in some
>   implementations.

The requirements of that paragraph allow the use of a single buffer.